# Google analytics tracking no heritage

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

In Google Analytics documentation they provide the next code:

[image: analytics documentation]

Is it possible to track a view without using heritage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. After You setup your defaultTracker in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like this;

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"your_tracking_id"];

[[GAI sharedInstance] setDefaultTracker:tracker];
```

You can use this in your class that is without heritage;

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"YourViewControllerName"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];   }
```